# Jescription of Multi-configuration project name

Tags: python, jenkins

I have  Multi-configuration project  that runs Project with parameters. For example it's build_python_version.

In  Multi-configuration project I added User-defined Axis with name  build_python_version and value `2.7 3.2 3.3 3.4`.

[image]

My problem is that when I look at the "Configuration Matrix", I see values of parameters without descriptions:

[image: I see values of parameters without descriptions]

Comment: It's unclear what your question is? It should be clear to you what the axes are, as you configured the job. But you can click on any of the balls (or hover over them to see the URL), and you'll get a page saying what each of the axis names and values are for that sub-job.

Comment: I have various python version, ansible version, falcon version and more than 2 params. I want add description of that axies. How can I?

Comment: You can't show the axis names directly, but you can write a description at the top of the job page using the "edit description" button.